# Mumble: Why is my forwarded port reported as closed from canyouseeme.org?

Tags: networking, router, mumble

I have set my router to forward the port for Mumble to my server machine on the LAN.
[image: Port forwarding set up on the router ZTE MF920/MR150-5]

External site (and Mumble users trying to connect to my client) report failure:
[image]

I can connect to the Mumble server on the LAN without issue. I have restarted the router. Have I set up the mapping incorrectly, or is there an issue with the Mumble server on 16.04?

Edit: I suspect my ISP may be blocking the port, since it's a SIM based network.

Comment: Could you give the output form `ufw status`?

Comment: It says, "Status: inactive"

Comment: Hm, that means that you firewall is inactive. But I personally tested a port I just opened and it also shows that there is no service.

Comment: In my case it didnt work because I didnt have the server running. But when I started the server it said success. Maybe thats thats what causes you problem too?

Comment: I can connect on the LAN without issue, so it is running. Thanks @Marton

Comment: So is it possible that your ISP is blocking Ports? And have you tried running other Services?

Answer (score 0):

run `netstat -an | grep 64738` to make sure the service is listening on 0.0.0.0 and NOT on 127.x.x.x

Comment: I get: 
tcp6       0      0 :::64738                :::*                    LISTEN     
udp6       0      0 :::64738                :::*                          

I'm starting to suspect my ISP is the issue and that the router is configured correctly.

Comment: Does your router get a public IP?

Comment: Yes, I have a public facing IP. That's how I was able to run the test with canyouseeme.org